# "Not a good example" questions should not be great example questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, example-questions, definition-phase

Area 51 has a mechanism for making sure that dubious questions are not counted among the five good off-topic questions: they need four times as many off-topic votes as on-topic votes. There should also be such a mechanism to avoid counting questions with many "not a good example" votes.

As an example, one of the off-topic questions for [Bioinformatics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6729?tab=offtopic&phase=definition#tab-top) is "What is the meaning of life?", with 24 off-topic votes and 14 bad-example votes. It should not count due to the disagreement.

Comment: I'd say that for every "not a good example" vote the question should require one more "good example" to be considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, for a question to be considered on/off-topic, it also needs at least four times as many on/off-topic votes as not-a-good-example votes.